# Define a macro to swap symbols

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I was wondering if there is any way, in C/C++, to swap symbols with macros.
For example, if I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef enum {
    A, B, C
} foo_t;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int i;
    foo_t foo[] = {A, B, C};

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(foo)/sizeof(*foo); i++)
        printf("%d ", foo[i]);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In the main I want to replace each occurrence of A with B, each occurrence of B with C and C with A. 
So I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef enum {
    A, B, C
} foo_t;

#define A B
#define B C
#define C A

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int i;
    foo_t foo[] = {A, B, C}; // Should became B, C, A

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(foo)/sizeof(*foo); i++)
        printf("%d ", foo[i]);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But this does not work, it is as if the macros A, B and C were not defined. I think it's due to the recursive definition (A is defined as B, B is defined as C, C is defined as A, which is defined as B, etc.)

Is there any other way to do this with a macro?

I'm not looking for the function search and replace provided by many text editors.

Comment: I would re-factor the code as this will lead to confusion.

Comment: Your macro definitions are circular. A is expanded to B which is immediately expanded to C which is immediately expanded to A. Here the expansion stops as the pre-processor detects the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can to this to reach your goal:

```
#define A A_
#define B B_
#define C C_

#include <stdio.h>
typedef enum {
    A, B, C
} foo_t;

#undef A
#undef B
#undef C

#define A B_
#define B C_
#define C A_

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int i;
    foo_t foo[] = {A, B, C}; // Should became B, C, A

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(foo)/sizeof(*foo); i++)
        printf("%d ", foo[i]);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
#define A 1
#define B 2
#define C 0

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int i;
  foo_t foo[] = {A, B, C}; // Should became B, C, A

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(foo)/sizeof(*foo); i++)
    printf("%d ", foo[i]);

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```